# How to programatically scroll a ScrollViewer to the top in uwp xaml?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have applied ScrollViewer to a user control which automatically scrolls to the bottom if height exceeds.
Now my page is closing having the scrollbar at the bottom position and it remains at the bottom when I reopen the page.

How can I reset the scrollbar to the top every time I open that page.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer">
              
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,40">
       </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollViewer` provides the **[ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview)** method, which can be used to adjust the scrolling state:

```cs
// scroll to top
myScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, 0, 1);
```

You can call this method after the page is loaded to scroll the `ScrollViewer` to the top.

---

**Update**

If you want to access the control on the page in the `ViewModel`, there are two ways:

**1. Public control**

This method means that you need to create a public page instance, and then expose the control in XAML, as shown below:

ScrollViewerPage.xaml

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" x:FieldModifier="public">
    <!-- your code -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

ScrollViewerPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public sealed partial class ScrollViewerPage : Page
{
    public static ScrollViewerPage Current;
    public ScrollViewerPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }
}
```

After the page is loaded, you can use this code to access the `ScrollViewer`.

```cs
ScrollViewerPage.Current.myScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, 0, 1);
```

**2. Define control variable/property in ViewModel**

You can define a variable or property (public) of type `ScrollViewer` in the `ViewModel`, and then assign a value to the property when the page loads, and then you can access the `ScrollViewer` by accessing the property in the `ViewModel`.

MyViewModel.cs

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ScrollViewer MyScrollViewer { get; set; }

    // Other code
}
```

ScrollViewerPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public ScrollViewerPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.MyScrollViewer = myScrollViewer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I access that myScrollViewer in ViewModel?

Comment: Hello, I updated the answer, please kindly check it.